вАдько чи вадькО - чоловіче ім'я
Як правильно ставити наголос в зменшеному чоловічому імені "Вадько" - на перший чи другий склад?

Ва́дько
Так зазначають щонайменше два джерела:

Власні імена людей : слов.-довід. (стр. 44) / Л. Г. Скрипник, Н. П. Дзятківська
Матеріали до «Російсько-українського словника власних імен людей» / Самойлова, І.


Наголос у імені "Вадько" ставиться на перший склад: Ва́дько.
https://slovnyk.ua/nagolos.php

Ce ne SUM, i tam ničoho ne pôdkazujeʼ, ščonamenše menê.

Підтримую коментатора Sǫ́tjnôstj — я не бачу, щоб на сайті https://slovnyk.ua/nagolos.php було написано, де наголос у слові Вадько.
